# SCP files from an IP

Tags: putty, scp

I have a folder of files on an IP that I want to download.
Can I do this using PUTTY?

I've tried using

```
scp user@servername:/home/folder-to-download C:\temp\
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 4):

If you're using putty, the command is `pscp`. Paul's `-r` tip is also relevant:

```
pscp -r user@servername:/home/folder-to-download C:\temp\
```

Comment: When I type that it just goes to next line with prompt '>'.
No folder is created and no files downloaded

Comment: odd. have you tried to pscp just an individual file from the directory?

Comment: Yeah, nothing. Perhaps a wrong user issue? Although would it prompt to say if this was the case?

Comment: Yeah that should generate an error. Can you connect/ssh to the machine w/ putty? Type `putty`. You'll get a dialog box. Type the `servername` that you're using into the `Host Name` field and click `Open`. Try to use user/pass to login.

Comment: Netwok error : connection timed out. So there must be a problem with the server

Comment: If you're typing this command into `bash` and it gives you a `>` prompt, I think that means it's interpreting the backslashes as escape characters, meaning that when you hit "Enter", it's interpreting that character as being part of the command. Try enclosing the Windows path in *single* quotation marks (`'C:\temp\'`) or doubling the backslashes (`C:\\temp\\ `).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it a recursive copy:

```
scp -r user@servername:/home/folder-to-download C:\temp\
```

See the [scp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) for a list of possible options, including `-r`.